# Implement Signal() using sigaction() in ubuntu

Tags: c, unix, network-programming, signals, handler

I am programming a client/server app where the client provides the file name, then the server sends it to client and finally the client will save it.

So I want to make signal handler to handle zombie problem between parent and child so this code for signal:

```
Sigfunc *
signal(int signo, Sigfunc *func)
{
    struct sigaction    act, oact;
 
    act.sa_handler = func;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (signo == SIGALRM) {
#ifdef    SA_INTERRUPT
        act.sa_flags |= SA_INTERRUPT;    /* SunOS 4.x */
#endif
    } else {
#ifdef    SA_RESTART
        act.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;        /* SVR4, 44BSD */
#endif
    }
    if (sigaction(signo, &act, &oact) < 0)
        return(SIG_ERR);
    return(oact.sa_handler);
}
/* end signal */
```

The filename is `myHeader.h`
and the error when compile the file is :

```
gcc -Wall -I/home/zmhnk/Desktop/ -o "myHeader" "myHeader.h" (in directory: /home/zmhnk/Desktop)
myHeader.h:281:1: error: unknown type name ‘Sigfunc’
myHeader.h:282:19: error: unknown type name ‘Sigfunc’
Compilation failed.
```

So how can this problem be solved?

Comment: Missing some `#include`? Here (Fedora) you have to include `<signal.h>`, and it is `sighandler_t`, no `Sigfunc` in sight.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `Sigfunc`, so place something like this in your header file:

```
typedef void (*Sigfunc)(int sig_no);
```

in your header file.

And since there's already a standard function named `signal` , you need to name your function something else.